# Unzipping a file that is on the server in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, zip

I want the user to be able to upload a folder to my server, but I read that this can't be done, but if you change it to a .zip file, then upload the .zip file like normal. I searched in some places and couldn't find out how to do it in asp.net (VB). Can anyone lead me in the correct direction? I haven't a clue about how to do this, otherwise I would have provided some code.
My Question: How would I go about unzipping a .zip file that is on the server in asp.net?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a step-by-step walkthrough in unzipping files using c# [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110129231321/http://www.ehow.com/how_7301924_unzip-file-c_.html). It's a WinForms example, but doing it in code-behind in asp.net is no different than WinForms

Fair warning, though, that a .zip file can contain anything, and you need to prevent against [malicious file execution](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2007-Malicious_File_Execution).

Comment: Yeah, I know, I have got all that covered =], and thanks for the quick answer

Comment: Sorry, my question is misleading, and I haven't properly asked it. I wanted to know, how would I unzip the .zip file that is on the server?

Comment: You would use the same code.  You first save the .zip file to the server (assuming you've already gotten this far) and then replace the path shown in this line of code: string zipFilePath = @"C:\ZipfilePath";  with the path you saved the file to.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that, but I have one more question, how would I upload a file/folder to my server without the user actually selecting the file/folder to upload. I want to make a backup function, so basically, the user clicks the 'backup' button and the data from my .exe file is uploaded to my server. Is this possible?

Comment: not from a web app, it's not.  You'd have to run something client-side. Imagine how dangerous it would be if websites had free reign in the visitor's file system.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I was just reading about that, so you're saying that an .exe can upload it though?

Comment: yes. I'd write an .exe that calls a web service. The web service function would take a byte array as a parameter, and I'd have the .exe deserialize the file to a byte array to pass to the service.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12004/discussion-between-user959631-and-david-stratton)

Answer (score 1):

This example is using `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile`, from [Microsoft Documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
            string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
            string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";

            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);

            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
        }
    }
}
```